# Error al deserializar XML sin etiqueta de cierre C#

Tags: c#, net, asp.net-core-5.0

Estoy consumiendo un servicio que en ocasiones me manda el XML completo y en otros casos solo la etiqueta de apertura.

Por ejemplo:

```
<amount>100</amount>
<amount/>
```

Ésta es mi propiedad y solo en el primer ejemplo funciona:

```
[XmlElement(ElementName = "amount")]
public double? Amount { get; set; }
```

Ésta es mi función para deserializar:

```
using(TextReader read = new StringReader(AESCrypto.decrypt(key, strResponse))) {
   oRes = (CENTEROFPAYMENTS)ser.Deserialize(read);
}
```

Comment: Agrega mas informacion al respecto, asi como la declaracion de las clases, aun sin revisar puedes verificar que si el texto contiene al inicio cierta etiqueta pues usas uno u otro clase de Deserializacion

Comment: Por desgracia es un problema que aún en 2022 sigue persistiendo. Te propongo la solución que yo uso.

Answer (score 2):

Desconozco si existe una manera más elegante de hacerlo, pero yo he terminado por eliminar las etiquetas vacías mediante una expresión regular de la siguiente manera:

```
string xmlLimpio = Regex.Replace(
    AESCrypto.decrypt(key, strResponse),
    @"<[a-zA-Z]+/>",
    ""
);
```

Para ello tendrás que cargar previamente el XML en una variable de tipo `string` y posteriormente usar dicha variable en tu código:

```
using (TextReader read = new StringReader(xmlLimpio)) {
   oRes = (CENTEROFPAYMENTS)ser.Deserialize(read);
}
```

Para reproducir tu problema y mostrarte la solución he usado este código:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Xml;

public class Pruebas
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "amount")]
    public double? Amount { get; set; }
}

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Pruebas i;
        i = deserializar(
            "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n<Pruebas><amount>5</amount></Pruebas>"
        );
        Console.WriteLine("Prueba 1: " + i.Amount);
        i = deserializar(
            "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n<Pruebas><amount/></Pruebas>"
        );
        Console.WriteLine("Prueba 2: " + i.Amount);
    }

    private static Pruebas deserializar(string xml)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Pruebas));
        /* Filtro las etiquetas vacías */
        string xmlLimpio = Regex.Replace(xml, @"<[a-zA-Z]+/>", "");
        TextReader reader = new StringReader(xmlLimpio);
        return (Pruebas)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }
}
```

Cuyo resultado sería:

```
Prueba 1: 5
Prueba 2:
```

Answer (score 0):

La recomendacion es que a tu propiedad, la declares con el atributo [XmlElement > IsNullable](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.isnullable)  en true

```
[XmlElement(ElementName = "amount", IsNullable = true)]
public double? Amount { get; set; }
```

Asi luego puedes enviar un elemento "nulleable" y que parsee correctamente, pero con estas dos opciones

- OPCION 1: Sin el elemento: Elemento de lista > En tu caso lo tienes pero facil seria que no venga en el xml el elemento "amount"
- OPCION 2: Recomendada (cuando la fuente formatea correctamente el xml), seria  que el elemento "ammount", con el atributo [xsi:nil](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#xsi_nil) con el valor true, para indicar que  es "nulo".
  Ejemplo:

Esto seria lo recomendado.

Pero en tu caso como no tienes posibilidad que desde el origen que genera el XML, pueda "formatearlo correctamente", puedes

- Propuesta 1: Tu propio formateador o deserializador de dicho elemento
- Propuesta 2: a los elementos que estan "vacios" recorrarlos como string y agregar el atributo [xsi:nil](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#xsi_nil) con valor true (es una opcion a la eliminacion de que propones en tu solucion, me parece mas elegante y mas estandar)

O sea la recomendacion seria tener algo asi en tu objeto para deserializar
(la propiedad que tenias pero con el atributo XmlIgnore, y luego una propiedad solo para propositos de deserializar)

```
    [XmlIgnore]
    public double? Amount { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "amount", IsNullable = true)]
    [Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never), DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    public string AmountOnlyJustToDeserialize
    {
        get
        {
            if (Amount.HasValue) {
                return Amount.Value.ToString("0.##");
            }
            return string.Empty;
        }
        set
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) {
                Amount = null;
            }
            else
            {
                Amount = double.Parse(value);
            }
            
        }
    }
```

Algunos enlaces que te pueden ayudar

- [XmlElement > IsNullable](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.isnullable)
- Atributo [xsi:nil](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#xsi_nil)

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guia

Comment: Por norma general de consumen servicios web de terceros a los que no puedes pedir al proveedor que elimine la etiqueta o agregue atributos adicionales. Yo ya había experimentado con `IsNullable`, pero sin éxito. ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo de código en el que consigas (con tus recomendaciones) deserializar el XML con el que tiene problemas el OP? Sobre todo me interesa tu propuesta *"Tu propio formateador o deserializador de dicho elemento"*.

Comment: Claro @OscarGarcia, si no tienes posibilidad de editar el origin no es una opcion (pero a veces en algunas oportunidades podemos dialogar con la otra empresa  e indicarle que mejore su API/WebService), pero bueno es para comentario nomas, pero vale tu aclaracion. Con respecto "tu propio formateador", hay varias formas pero mira el codigo de ejemplo de la propiedad "AmountOnlyJustToDeserialize", pruebalo y veras que funciona con el tuyo (tendrias que agregar esta propiedad tu clase donde esta Amount ) e ingorar que se deserialice "automaticamente Amount